# Using SQL to get the continuous range of table

Tags: sql, hana

Here is a table named track and have three columns: `time`, `speed`, `isOverSpeed`, like below

```
TIME      Speed IsOverSpeed
10:00:01    76      1
10:00:11    58      0
10:00:21    70      1
10:00:31    70      1
10:00:41    90      1
10:00:51    40      0
10:01:01    30      0
10:01:11    80      1
10:01:21    20      0
```

What I want is to calculate how many times and how long a car which is `overspeed`, the requirement is the continuous `overspeed` records will be count as 1 time, in the example, there is 3 times `overspeed` not 4. I am thinking using the window function but seems it does not work. could anyone has an idea?
PS. the result should be 3 times, 50 seconds.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Show your code how you've already tried to achive this

Comment: thanks. I am using the SAP HANA database, I guess nobody knew this, so the standard SQL will be help. Currently I use cursor but the performance is not good.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) As Cnt, SUM(SECONDS_BETWEEN(dt.prevTime, dt.TIME)) As someTime
FROM (
    SELECT t1.TIME, MAX(t2.TIME) As prevTime
    FROM aTable t1
        JOIN
        aTable t2 ON t1.TIME > t2.TIME 
    WHERE t1.IsOverSpeed = 1
    GROUP BY t1.TIME) dt
```

Comment: thanks shA.t, but this can't handle the case which more than 3 rows are continuous overspeed , and the 3rd and 4th row are counted as 2 but should be 1.

Comment: @GuowenYan Can you please give me some sample data and expected result? ;).

Comment: I edited the question to give the expected result. thanks!